# Cannot display drive pictures on my web app

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail

First of all forgive my english i'm french (we can't be perfect).

I made a web app with angular and a Springboot API REST for my internship. This web app is directly connected to the drive (protected) so you need to identify with the google access_token with the google API. This is absolutely working and i get the right token.

The web app were slow because at each connection i loaded a lot of pictures with the drive API.

My problem came up when i decided to store the pictures URL (format : https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6...... ) in my database so i won't have to load them each time someone connect to the web app.

It was perfectly working on my computer so i went on and continued the development of the app. But when we had to test it on the users computers we realized that when someone have 2 gmail adresses connected on his browser the images won't display at all even if one of these 2 adresses has the rights to see it.

I don't even succeed when i try to reproduce the bug on my computer when both my personnal and professionnal mails are connected i can see the pictures. Even when my personnal mail is the "default one". The only way i can reproduce this is to connect on my web app and then disconnect from this mail on the browser. Maybe because the URLs were created with my gmail adress but i don't think this is the problem because my project manager is able to see them with another mail.

It's been almost a week that i am looking for an answer to this problem but i can't figure it out. The main thing that surprises me is that on my computer and my project manager there is no problem but on almost all the users computer they can't see the pictures.

I guess if i could force the token to use to validate the access to the pictures i would be able to display them...

Test that i did :

- connect on the users computer with only the mail who have access WORKING
- As soon as i connect the second adress i can't see the pictures
- When on my computer i tried every combination it's always working

Thank you for reading this, any comment will be helpfull.

EDIT : i can't give my folder a public access those pictures can't be public (3500 people pictures)